# Node - Simple xml API Request

Tags: node.js, xml, api, express, request

I'm using the latest node.js (and express) to make an API call to a site that returns... XML... Ugh >_>.

I've scowered the web and found a million different ways, but I don't know the latest, most up to date / best way to make a request and get a response in node/express.

I tried using https://github.com/request/request and did the following:

```
var sendJsonResponse = function(res, status, content) {
    res.status(status);
    res.json(content);
};

var token = request
    .get('some-website.com/api/stuff')
    .on('response', function(response) {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        console.log(response.headers['content-type']);
    });

sendJsonResponse(res, 200, token);
```

in the `console.log` statements I get `200` and then `application/xml;charset=utf-8`.

But on my page I don't get the xml I'm looking for. Any ideas? I've tried using https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js to attempt to "parse" the response, in case node just can't handle the xml response, but to no avail.

```
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
parser.parseString(response, function(err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
    console.log('Done');
});
```

Any help on accessing an API using Node and actually using the XML response, please?

***EDIT ANSWER***

For the Node.js request and xml parsing of the returned xml content:

```
var request = require('request');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');

var sendJsonResponse = function(res, status, content) {
    res.status(status);
    res.json(content);
};

/* GET XML Content*/
module.exports.dsRequest = function(req, res) {

    var parser = new xml2js.Parser();

    request('url_for_xml_request', function(error, response, body) {
        parser.parseString(body, function(err, result) {
            sendJsonResponse(res, 200, result);
        });

    });

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work, because request is **async**, you should write like below:

```
 var sendJsonResponse = function(res, status, content) {
      res.status(status);
      res.json(content);
};

 request.get('http://some-website.com/api/stuff', function (err,response, body) {
       sendJsonResponse(res, 200, body);
});
```

Comment: That's roughly what I did, but I was also having trouble interpreting the response, cause it was XML. I edited my original question and put my new working code in.